# Does spark streaming write ahead log saves all received data to HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

If write ahead logs are enabled in spark streaming does all the received data gets written to HDFS path   ? or it only writes the metadata. 
How does clean up works , does HDFS path gets bigger and bigger  up everyday do I need to write an clean up job to delete data from  write ahead logs folder ? 
what actually does write ahead log folder has ?

Thanks 
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enable WAL, data is being serialized and saved into HDFS. Therefore, all your assumptions are right, HDFS file gets bigger. However, it gets cleaned up with a separate process. I haven't had my hands on an actual reference that explains this, but you can see that in the source code. In addition, it introduces a longer processing time as those are processes running alongside your transformations and actions

Comment: so by default there is a clean up process in spark , so I don't need to worry about the WHL directory size. thanks

Comment: Good question. 

Write Ahead Logs are used to do both - write data and write metadata when needed. When data wal is enabled using the conf spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable, data received by receivers are written to the data WAL by the executors. In some cases, like Direct Kafka and Kinesis, the record identifies are written to another metadata WAL by the driver. The metadata WAL is always enabled.All WALs take care of their cleanup @TD Tathagata Das